# SQLSTATE[08001] - Named Pipes Provider - Laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, xampp

Estou recebendo um erro na hora de conectar a aplicação com o banco.

O arquivo .env está configurado corretamente com as definições do banco, o erro que tenho como retorno:

```
SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [67]. (SQL: select top 1 * from [stakeholders] where [login] = rmendes)
```

O projeto é feito em laravel, e o banco está em `localhost`.

Utilizo o **SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO 2014**

Imagem do erro no navegador....
           [image: Named Pipes Provider]

Será que pode ser isso a causa do meu problema?
        [image: Pipes named]

Comment: Para corrigir o erro, basta ativar a opção de comunicação via protocolo TCP/IP do SQL Server.

Comment: Como está fazendo para "subir a aplicação"? Só copiou os arquivos para os lugares corretos?

Comment: é que este banco estava em produção ,aew pra eu fazer os teste eu fiz um backup e criei um local ,  localhost\sqlexpress  configurei no arquivo.env do laravel e até na database.php do próprio laravel  apontando para o banco local... e subo usando o `php artisan serve` ... é isso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente você deverá habilitar a possibilidade de conexão remota, o protocolo Named-Pipes e TCP/IP como também o serviço SQL Browser.(na teoria)

Mas tente o seguinte:

Desative temporariamente o Firewall do Windows e teste uma vez mais:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Certifique-se de que o NetBIOS esteja ativado nas configurações de TCP / IP do adaptador de rede que você está usando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Certifique-se de que os protocolos do SQL Server estejam habilitados através do SQL Server Configuration Manager:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Experimente também uma combinação de duas ou mais opções acima.

Comment: Darlei .O mesmo erro ainda continua .. e também fiz as combinações ,pra ver se até o erro mudava e mesmo assim ,não mudou...

Comment: este tipo de erro tem haver com o laravel ou configuração do sql server ?? só pra tirar essa dúvida minha

Comment: Ao que tudo indica  o Laravel tenta fazer a conexão com o server mas não consegue. A razão mais comum dedesse erro é que essa tentativa de conexão falhou porque que essa fonte de dados DSN ou ODBC tentou fazer uma conexão usando os soquetes TCP / IP Net-Library, que é Dbmssocn.dll. Como o SQL Server não está ouvindo as conexões recebidas para clientes sockets TCP / IP, a conexão falha.

Comment: aew eu pesquiso como no google?? como configurar os sockets TCP/IP  do sql ?

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui -> https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/195566/prb-odbc-connection-failed-sqlstate-08001-dbmssocn

Comment: eu pedi para o DBA Master criar um ambiente de teste pra mim,para evitar estas coisas...com isto aceito as respostas anteriores.